# is this possible to relate two indexes in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, laravel-5, laravel-scout

Iam new in elasticsearch.I integrated elasticsearch to my existing laravel app.

I have two tables.**parents** and **childrens**. When each parent created ,it create a document with index name **parent**.same as childrens.., each childrens created creates document with index name **childrens**. I want to map these two model in elasticsearch. how i will implement this. i used **"tamayo/laravel-scout-elastic": "^3.0",** to integrate with my laravel app.
Please help.thanks in advance

Comment: You can use the parent-child structure available in Elasticsearch

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/indexing-parent-child.html